# Can a GCP project be disabled using an API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Use Case : Need to disable a google project using an API .

Also wanted to know whether a project number or project id will help in doing that.

From the Cloud billing API I was able to execute the following command :
curl -X GET 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" 
-H "x-goog-user-project: project-id" 
"https://billingbudgets.googleapis.com/v1/billingAccounts/billing-account-id/budgets/budget-id"

I was able to get the project number, however needed to know how to use this project number to disable a project or unlink it from Billing